# How to check the RAM configuration and RAM usage on your ubuntu terminal?

Tags: terminal, ram

How to check the RAM configuration and RAM usage on your ubuntu terminal?

Comment: `free -m` command will give you RAM  and swap status

Answer (score 1):

Use `top` or you can install `htop` from repos (`htop` is more friendly)